# How can we write an XSD file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, xml, magento-2.0, validation

I'm looking for some documentation or tutorial for creating custom xsd in Magento 2 but failed to find any good resource. I already found [URN Schema Validation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/XSD-XML-validation.html) article in Magento 2 official documentation but its failed to explain how exactly we can write a new one. Can you share your experience with me and provide something useful to get started writing custom XSDs ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to Magento

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I think you are right. However, I think this question will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: did you get how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD is not Magento specific technology, it is common. It is why you should find documentation not in magento devdocs portal.

You can use  W3School docs for example http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp

Comment: I knew that XSD is not Magento specific, but if I read more about it via the link you mentioned, I figured it out why I couldn't find related article in Magento 2 documentation.