# What are the different xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation in Magento 2 and when to use them?

Tags: magento2, configuration, xml, di

Looking through Magento 2 `di.xml` files there are various types of `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`

When should we be using each schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the type of XML file you create.

Basically, all the XSD files can be found under the `lib/internal/Magento/Framework` folder, here is the list on 2.1.2:

[image]

For example, if you create a `etc/acl.xml` in your module, you'll have to use the `acl.xsd` file.

There are a few details about it in the official documentation:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/XSD-XML-validation.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-create.html#config-files-validate

My personal practice is: when I want to create an XML file, I check the same type of file in the core and get the URN schema from it.

Also, you can create your own XSD in case you want to use a custom type of XML: [How can we write an XSD file in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113839/how-can-we-write-an-xsd-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: makes perfect sense, thank you for the detailed answer